# Как поместить передаваемое пользователем значение в переменную, а потом ее использовать в другой функции

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Как передать значение в следующую функцию в данном случае?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "gruzchik")
def replenish_balans(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Какое колличество грузчиков Вам необходимо?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, take_money)


def take_money(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перевод на карту", callback_data="karta"))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Для пополнения счета на {message.text} выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Некоректный ввод\nВведите колличество цифрами")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_money)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "karta")
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
       types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Я оплатил", callback_data="2.2"))
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text=для заказа "**Сюда нужно значение которое ввел пользователь**",
                          reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Я так понимаю принимать ответы вы не любите? Ну тогда и ответов вы не получите

Comment: Клиент вбивает какое количество грузчиков ему необходимо, далее рабатывает функция 'take_money' которая предлагает выбрать вариант оплаты, после нажатия на кнопку 'karta' чтоб пришло сообщение в которую нужно поместить введенное пользователем число грузчиков умноженное на тарифную ставку к примеру 600 руб час за 1 грузчика! Спасибо, уже 2 раз на просьбу откликаетесь!)

Comment: @oleksandrigo, поможете пожалуйста?

Comment: если вы начнете принимать ответы то может быть

Comment: Честно не понимаю, я благодарен за прошлый ответ ваш и редактирование кода который я прислал в этом сообщении, я ответил на ваше уточнение в какую и откуда перенести переменную! Нужна ваша помошь, я бы даже ваши контакты для связи попросил за помощь с благодарствием))

Comment: Верней связь нужна с Ввами)нужен наставник хороший, в этой сфере я пока 0 но 2 месяца головой до "крови"долблюсь не прекращая)) Интересна эта тема

Comment: нужен наставник telegram: @Vihr1988

Answer (score 0):

Уточните пожалуйста, значений какой переменной из какой функции в какую нужно передать? А так, для таких целей можно использовать два метода: return variable и назначение какой-то переменной глобальной. Вариант с return:

```
a = int(input(f'Введите число, которое желаете возвести в квадрат: '))
def square(num):
    num = num**2
    return num
print(f'Квадратом числа {a} является - {square(a)}')
```

Вариант с глобальной переменной, который скорее всего вам подойдет больше чем с return:

```
a = int(input(f'Введите число, которое желаете возвести в квадрат: '))
def square():
    global num
    num = a**2
    
square()
print(f'Квадратом числа {a} является - {num}')
```

Если предположим вам требуется передать значение переменной "A", которой присваивается значение в функции №1 в функцию №2, то можно:

1. Объявить ее глобальной в переменной №1
2. "Запустить" функцию №1
3. Использовать в ф-ии №2

Пример:

```
def first():
global A
A = input()

def second():
print(A)

first()
second()
```

Comment: Я пока мало понимаю к сожалению, пайтон начал учить с создания бота, как внедрить данное условие в функцию, будь добр, помоги, я биться буду сутки не меньше)

Comment: Для того чтобы я смог лучше вам помочь, Уточните пожалуйста, значений какой переменной из какой функции в какую нужно передать?

Comment: Клиент вбивает какое количество грузчиков ему необходимо, далее рабатывает функция 'take_money' которая предлагает выбрать вариант оплаты, после нажатия на кнопку 'karta' чтоб пришло сообщение в которую нужно поместить введенное пользователем число грузчиков умноженное на тарифную ставку к примеру 600 руб час за 1 грузчика!

Comment: Извиняюсь,может не так излагаю суть

Answer (score 0):

Возможно попробуйте этот вариант. Я так и не понял что конкретно вам требуется, что за тарифная ставка, какие 600 руб час за грузчика, и в целом о чем это, но я сделал так, чтобы та сумма, которую пользователь выбирает, которую вы еще проверяете на численность, присваивалась глобальной переменной summ и в дальнейшем поднималась в функции choise_service в месте, где вы написали комментарий "*Сюда нужно значение которое ввел пользователь*"

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "gruzchik")
def replenish_balans(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Какое количество грузчиков Вам необходимо?")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, take_money)


def take_money(message: types.Message):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        global summ
        summ = message.text
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перевод на карту", callback_data="karta"))
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Для пополнения счета на {message.text} выберите способ оплаты", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Некорректный ввод\nВведите количество цифрами")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, take_money)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "karta")
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
       types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Я оплатил", callback_data="2.2"))
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                          message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text=summ,
                          reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: Поставил бы 100 класов, но я так понял они не учитываюстся с моим 0  рейтингом тебе( Тем не менее спасибо! нужен наставник telegram: @Vihr1988